# Access windows PATH variable from git bash

Tags: windows, git-bash

I'm trying to set append a new item to the windows PATH variable trough git bash in an installer script. The script requires git bash. I'm having problems with git bash PATH variable containing other things than the windows PATH.

I'm trying to use `setx PATH "$PATH;newITEM;"` but the git bash PATH variable adds things to the path making it to long for windows.

Please advice.